# Proper Naming Convention For Parameter of Type List<long>

Tags: c#, rename

I wrote a method in c# which takes the input parameter of type List and i kept the parameter variable name as cardIDList.

And from code review feedback, they asked me to change the parameter variable name from cardIDList to cardIDs saying that appending list is not a right naming convention from Microsoft standard.

I tried to find the truthiness of that feedback in google, but I couldn't find like that anywhere. I need the help on this.

From :

```
public void DoSomething(List<long> cardIDList)
```

To :

```
public void DoSomething(List<long> cardIDs)
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)?

Comment: There is no need to include `List` in the name since the **type** of the variable tells you that already.

Comment: This is all subjective, the only rule is to follow the rules of the people who are giving them to you

Answer (score 2):

Common naming conventions can be found here https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md
and here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-parameters says:

> CONSIDER using names based on a parameter’s meaning rather than the
>   parameter’s type.

First of all - why do you take List as a parameter? You should allow the parameter to be as generic as possible - if you only need collection of elements and their count, use ICollection. Even better IEnumerable if you want to only iterate through the list or IReadOnlyCollection if you want to avoid accidental item change. It will be much easier to write unit tests for this method or override it in the future.

As you can see, type of parameter can be changed in the future and it shouldn't affect the naming. Putting "list" in the parameter name is redundant because we already know the type of that parameter. Now what should you do if you want for example to change the type to IEnumerable? Change it to cardIDEnumerable?